# jquery select a drop down box of a selected value

Tags: jquery

Using jquery i need to select a drop down box (get this object) which has a selected value of 3..How to do this

```
<div class="selDiv">
<select class="opts">
<option  value="DEFAULT">Default</option>
<option value="1" selected>Selection 1</option>
<option value="2">Selection 2</option>
</select>
<select class="opts">
<option value="DEFAULT">Default</option>
<option value="3" selected>Selection 1</option>
<option value="4">Selection 2</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean "select a drop down box", give it focus?

Comment: `<select>` elements need name attributes. Also, `<select>` elements can't have more than one selected option unless you specify the multiple attribute.

Comment: `var $select = $('select').filter(function() { return this.value == 3 });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$('select :selected[value="3"]').closest('select').focus()
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/wCRxb/3/)